# Android Emulator not rendering Text/EditTextViews Properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Screenshot below is from the emulator. For some reason some letters are not rendering properly. After inputting data, the view re-renders showing the missing letters. Emulator used is **Nexus 4 KitKat**.

[Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yxYF.jpg)

Recent changes made to source code:

- Upgraded to `buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"` in application module `build.gradle`
- Upgraded to `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'` `'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'` in application module `build.gradle`

On actual device **Nexus 6p Nougat 7.1.1**, letters are rendering and showing normally.

[Device Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1owQJ.jpg)

Comment: it may be emulator's problem.

Comment: Have you tried with another emulator?

Comment: It 's a emulator's bug in Nougat, I found this problem in  last day.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper: have tried it with a tablet 10.1 Lollipop emulator, no issues found there.

Comment: @Yat3s: tried nougat emulator, no issues found there. Only the KitKat emulator is showing the issue. Have tried it on Samsung S3 KitKat, no issues found there. Going to do a wipe next time and see if it'll fix the issue.

Comment: Tried wiping data of KitKat emulator, issue still showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New versions of the system images were released recently, KitKat was among them. Just downloaded via Android SDK Manager and updated it, issue got fixed and text was being rendered normally.